# Is Google play billing service open source?

Tags: android, android-service, in-app-billing

I want to make an app that has in-app payment inside it. But i want to implement in-app payments completely independently and not use Google Play or other markets in-app payments service. Since all Android marketplaces have built in-app payment services alike, I have guessed that all markets use the same source code for their apps and this part of the market code is open source (all of them copy `GooglePlay` market source code). Can anyone give me useful information about creating in-app payment services?
Also, I don't want to use inventive methods , and i seek to learn how android markets create built-in in-app payment service in their app and why all of them have same implementation (for users)!!!

Comment: "Is Google play billing service open source?" -- no, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks , but why all android markets have same code to implementing in-app purchase . all of them use this library as sample for in app billing : `https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive`

Comment: I do not know what you consider "android markets" to mean. The sample that you linked to is three years old and might not work with Google's current in-app billing service.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to speak to "all Android marketplaces." To sell in-app products and subscriptions for apps published through the Google Play Store, your app needs to integrate/implement Google Play Billing. Google Play is a separate entity from Android and so the code for Google Play is not open source. However we do provide the [Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/classes) and the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher) with [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview) and [samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDriveKotlin). I hope this helps clarify.

Comment: Do you think that android app markets that have in-app payments similar to Google Play, have not used ready-made codes and designed their own in-app service separately? for example  check this link [link](http://developers.cafebazaar.ir/en/docs/iab/) . this is an android market in-app billing documentation . its exactly the same of google play documentation just developer needs to change 3 line :payment permission , `IabHelper` Line 267 and 268 (service bind name and the market package name) .